# How are names ending in “-s” perceived?

Tags: grammatical-number, names, phonology

Most English nouns are inflected for grammatical number by adding *-s* — e.g., *cat* and *cats*, where *cats* is and sounds plural.

So, I wonder, since *Lucas*, *Nicholas*, and other English names end with *-s*, do they sound plural, or evoke plurality, to a native listener?

Comment: -1 We recognize first names as being *names* which people are born with. Why should there be any confusion?

Answer (score 8):

No, they don’t.

Plus you should note that they end in an unvoiced /s/ sound.  If they were plurals, they would end in a voiced /z/ sound.  If you somehow had one *“luca”* (whatever that might be) and hence several *“lucas”*, the latter would end in /z/ not in /s/ the way *Lucas* does.

Think about *Ramses*, *Hercules*, *Socrates*, *Menzies*, which really do all end in /z/.  Nobody thinks of those as more than one of each of those folks. Similarly, *trapeze* ends in a voiced /z/, but isn’t perceived as plural either.

Even with nouns ending in *-s* which are inflectionally invariant between singular and plural — words like *series* and *species* — you seldom see confusion in native speakers.

The place where native speakers sometimes stumble with forming their singulars and plurals is when English has wholesale-imported both the singular and plural forms of a  classical word from Latin or Greek, and word is expected to still follow the rules of an alien declension.  They’ll see words **that are already plural** like *bacteria*, *errata*, *criteria*, or *phenomena*, and for lack of  a final *-s* will occasionally misconstrue those as singulars instead and so end up creating “double plurals” like **bacterias*, **erratas*, **criterias*, and **phenomenas*.   (For the record, the respective singulars are *bacterium, erratum, criterion, phenemenon*.)

A closely related issue occurs with words like *crisis*, whose plural is *crises*. It is not uncommon to see people say *crisises* for the plural. It’s hard to fault them on that one.

Comment: What does voiced have to do with it?

Comment: @bib Words ending in /s/ instead of /z/ are not plurals to our ear.

Comment: *Locks, pits, tics, riffs, cups?*

Comment: @bib Those have unvoiced consonants before them, not vowels like *Lucas*.

Comment: Understood, but your suggestion that voicelessness is the criterion seems overbroad.

Comment: @bib I don’t know any English plural that ends in vowel + /s/.

Comment: Luca is a girl's name, so you can have one Lucas sat next to two Lucas (or Luca's, if you prefer, to disambiguate).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  In Italy, Luca is a boy's name. I've never heard of it being a girl's name elsewhere; unlike Andrea (/ˈændriə/ AN-dree-ə)
which is usually a girl's name in English speaking countries but in Italy, Andrea (/ɑːnˈdreɪ.ə/ahn-DRAY-ə) stands for Andrew and is always a  male name. So, you could have two Andreas (girls) sitting next to each other in class.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, “My name is Luca / I live on the second floor / I live upstairs from you / Yes I think you've seen me before”. :-)

Comment: Correcting myself here: In that song, the girl is actually called _Luka_ with a k, not with a c. Luca is a Hungarian variant of Lucy, though, and I doubt most Anglophones would know off-bat to pronounce it [ˈlutˢɒ].

Answer (score 2):

No! Why should names ending in 's' sound plural any more than any other noun ending in 's', such as *ass, bass, guess, kiss,* etc.?

Comment: As tchrist said, they would if they had a /z/ sound.

Comment: Trevor, I think the answer is oversimplified, if not another case of wrong information. Maybe if you convert it into a comment is better to avoid confusion for future visitors.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Please explain what you mean by "wrong information" and "oversimplified".

Comment: **Dance** ends with an "s" sound (obviously, we don't *see* whether words ends with the letter S or not) so do **trance**; **face**; **rice**; **lettuce** etc.. etc.. native speakers don't mistake these words as being plural. The point being that if you hear the request, *"Can I have a glass of juice?"* you don't think the person is asking for two glasses of different juices.

Comment: @user814064 the OP asked whether names ending in S sound plural to native speakers. Thomas for example is singular, but the OP believes it might be cause of ambiguity because of its final S "sound". I don't see where /ɪz/ comes into it.

Comment: Sorry!!! I'll delete all those comments!

Comment: @user814064 no, I'm sorry. I didn't mean to sound as if I were shouting. I was in a hurry to go to work, and the exclamation mark just reflected my frenetic mood. Sorry :)